# Should I create new table, or add new columns to existing one for song lyrics?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'd like to ask for some advice in whether I should create a new table or just add some new columns to existing table?

Honestly I've been thinking about this whole day and I really don't know.

So basically here's the structure of `song` table.

```
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int(6)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Title      | char(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Type       | char(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Singer     | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Youtube    | char(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Score      | double    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| Ratings    | int(8)    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| Favourites | int(7)    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In this I store information about songs obviously. And yesterday I thought I would add a feature on my site to check the lyrics of the available songs. I'm only planning to add the lyrics in 2 different languages, English and German **for now.**

That being said, I don't know if it would be better to just add some new columns like `English_lyrics` and `German_lyrics` to the `song` table, or I should create a new one, called `lyrics`, with these two columns and the ID of the song, `SongID`. This way I would just select the lyrics using `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

As per normalization, you should not have similar value attributes in multiple columns. In future, let's say, if you have to add 10 more languages later, your table will become huge. Moreover, adding new columns in a table with lots of data in a production environment is not so easy. Relational data should not be considered like a Flat Excel file. Searching for a combination of languages in lyrics will not be easy as well. Another issue could be that you will have lots of `NULL` values, because not all songs would have lyrics in all the languages. `NULL` is a special value, and handling it requires special care while formulating queries, and lots of common mistakes happen due to not accounting for the `NULL`.

Instead, you can create a new table, let's say, `songs_lyrics`. It will have three columns, *viz.*, song_id (Foreign Key to ID in songs table), language_id (Foreign Key to ID in a language master table), lyrics (text containing the lyrics in the specific language). You will also have a composite Primary Key on `(song_id, language_id)`

```sql
CREATE TABLE songs_lyrics (
  song_id INT NOT NULL, 
  language_id INT NOT NULL, 
  lyrics TEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (song_id, language_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (song_id) REFERENCES song(ID), 
  FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES language(ID)
) engine= InnoDB;
```

You will also need to create the Master table for the languages:

```sql
CREATE TABLE language (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: There are standards for languages; use them instead of needing another table.  Locales are like 'en_US', 'de_DE'.  A British song might be 'en_UK'.

Answer (score 0):

Plan for growth by storing the lyrics in a normalised way using a separate table.

The advantages would be:

- You can add more langauges easily should you expand to new languages in the future
- If MySQL is set to create one table per file you can manage the storage of your lyric table differently to the others (e.g. the song table could live on some small fast storage while the lyrics table lives on some more cost effective storage*)

*I'm aware that unless the database is many many gigabytes big this may not really be an issue. But it's something to consider.